# Vimeo JS API - Froogaloop - Finish event calls immediately/too early?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

According to the [vimeo js-api doc](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api), the event `finish - Fires when the video playback reaches the end.`

For some reason, I can't get this to work, the `finish` event always calls immediately, am I doing something wrong?

I am trying to make an embedded video disappear when it is finished playing. I have followed [this example by Drew Baker](http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html) but simply cannot get the `finish` event to call properly.

I have made a very straightforward [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/OneBIXIc/1/) to demonstrate the issue.

This behaviour seems to be occurring on Safari, Chrome and Firefox (on mac).

--

JS Code from JSBIN:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('iframe.vimeo').each(function(){
    Froogaloop(this).addEvent('ready', ready);
  });

  function ready(playerID){
    Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('play', play(playerID));
    Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('seek', seek);
    Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('finish', onFinish(playerID));

    Froogaloop(playerID).api('play');
  }

  function play(playerID){
    alert(playerID + " is playing!!!");
  }

  function seek() {
    alert('Seeking');
  }

  function onFinish(playerID) {
    alert(playerID + " finished!!!");
    $('#'+playerID).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing functions instead of passing the function reference to the `addEvent` method.

```
Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('play', play);
Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('seek', seek);
Froogaloop(playerID).addEvent('finish', onFinish);
```

Note that `Froogaloop` passes the `playerID` as an argument to the `play` callback function, I'm not certain that it passes the `playerID` as an argument to the `finish` callback function (although I'm guessing it probably does).

Comment: Ah, you are correct. By combining the Drew Baker example with the Vimeo documentation, I was able to get it to work finally by not including playerID in the `addEvent`. I've updated the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OneBIXIc/3/)